# Изменение состояния полей формы react

Tags: reactjs

При вводе чего-либо в одном инпуте, состояние меняется во всех инпутах.
То есть начинаю что-то набирать, и знаки появляются и в других полях.
Безусловно, где-то есть глупая ошибка.
Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему.

RegistrationForm.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Input from './Input';
import SubmitButton from './Button.jsx';
import SocialButtons from './SocialButtons'
import CheckboxLabel from './Checkbox'

const style = {
    inputStyle: {
        margin: 12,
    },
      import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';




const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textField: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 350,
  },
});

class ComposedTextField extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { type } = this.props;
    const { name } = this.props;
    const { placeholder } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.props;
    const { onChange } = this.props;


    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
       <TextField
            required
            id="required"
            label={placeholder}
            className={classes.textField}
            margin="normal"
            type={type}
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
       />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ComposedTextField.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ComposedTextField);
```

Input.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';




const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textField: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 350,
  },
});

class ComposedTextField extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { type } = this.props;
    const { name } = this.props;
    const { placeholder } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.props;
    const { onChange } = this.props;


    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
       <TextField
            required
            id="required"
            label={placeholder}
            className={classes.textField}
            margin="normal"
            type={type}
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
       />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ComposedTextField.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ComposedTextField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если приведенные вами 2 файла это и есть 2 инпута, то осмелюсь предположить что вы в onChange им отдаете одну и ту же функцию.

Было бы очень здорово если бы вы привели пример родительского компонента в котором вызываются 2 данных инпута.